# scilab-mode : how to interpret a .sci file?

Tags: shell

I work on  ubuntu 14.04 with scilab installed. I put Alexander Vigodner's `scilab.el` in my `init.el` load path and I created a `scilab-startup.el` file loaded by the init file.

My question is, how to interpret a `.sci` file opened with emacs ?

For instance, if there is only `2+2` in `test.sci`, when I have opened the file (emacs recognized it and loaded the scilab-mode), how to obtain `4` ?

Comment: You can test M-x Scilab-shell command and use scilab command in its shell. (But I could n't use this command.)

Answer (score 1):

After opening the `sci`-file start Scilab by the menu item "Scilab" -> "Start Scilab".
Afterwards you can use the key binding <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-b</kbd> to run the command `scilab-shell-run-buffer` for the file buffer of your `sci`-file.

EDIT after comment of [p-a](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/10056/p-a):

Oh, sorry, I just noticed that `scilab-shell-run-buffer` is a function defined in my setup. The corresponding lines are:

```el
(defun scilab-shell-run-buffer ()
  "Run scilab on buffer."
  (interactive)
  (scilab-shell-run-region (point-min) (point-max)))

(add-hook 'scilab-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                   (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'scilab-shell-run-line)
                   (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-r") 'scilab-shell-run-region)
                   (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-b") 'scilab-shell-run-buffer)))
```

Comment: `scilab-shell-run-buffer` doesn't seem to exist, but I used `scilab-shell-run-region` and obtained an error : "Scilab shell must be non busy to do that".

Comment: Please, have a look at the `*Scilab*`-buffer. Maybe, the scilab process gave some output there that helps to solve the problem. By the way, I added `scilab-shell-run-buffer` to my answer. (The missing function was my bad.)